# Could it be black screen on an otherwise good laptop without hard drive?

Tags: boot, laptop, ssd, blank-screen, physical-damage

The M.2 SSD hard drive of my laptop is physically damaged: a visual damage is seen in the middle of the card, and the chip that appears damaged gets very hot while attempting to boot.

Both with and without that damaged hard drive, the laptop responds to the power button, keyboard lights go up, but nothing appears on the screen. I would buy the replacement SSD, but I do not like that the screen remains black also with SSD removed. This may show that more damaged has been done for the laptop that I already could not repair. For the functional laptop, I would expect some BIOS messages on the screen even when booting without the hard drive.

Is it theoretically possible for the laptop without SSD drive to show no output on the display when starting and still be otherwise in a working technical condition? The SSD is rather expensive just to buy and try.

Comment: It should post, and allow you into the BIOS to select a boot device/boot order. What about plugging an an external VDU using the VGA/HDMI port?

Comment: It is EXTREMELY UNLIKELY that the problem is just the SSD if the system is not POSTing - its probably not worth spending money on an an SSD for it.

Comment: Understand. This is the answer I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily test the hardware components of your computer by booting a live DVD/USB such as the [Ubuntu live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454) and running a live session without installing Ubuntu. Running an Ubuntu live session will provide you with most of the information that you need to know. For more information you can install the *hw-probe* snap package. hw-probe can be installed in a live USB session with the following command:

```
sudo snap install hw-probe
```

hw-probe is a tool to check operability of computer hardware. Just run one simple command to check hardware:

```
sudo hw-probe -all -upload
```

The results of `sudo hw-probe -all -upload` will show whether the hardware components in your computer including BIOS/UEFI, CPU, memory, motherboard, graphics card, and networking are working in a tabular format.

[image]